# How to make normal div blocks responsively on top of the Yii framework with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I've managed to build a site using the YII framework. I also installed the Bootstrap Extension which allows me to easily implement responsive widgets. My problem comes in with the rest of the site. Let's say I want:

- A header
- A menu
- Main Content
- A Footer

The menu is the easy part, because I simply use the Bootstrap widget like this:

```
<?php 
     $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', array(
     'type'=>'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
     'stacked'=>false, // whether this is a stacked menu
     'items'=>array(
       array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
       array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
       array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
     ),
   )); 
?>
```

So my question is around making the rest of the site responsive. So: Is there an easy way to create "blocks" that will automatically be responsive too? Or is it simply a matter of creating divs and styling it responsively? in other words, is the bootstrap extension limited to specific components and therefore the remaining layout relies on the designer to sort out using CSS?

Comment: Take a look at the Twitter Bootstrap documentation. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: But is there a native way to call these via the YII implementation. Check this --> http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/index.html ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on what your putting in your content. `<div>` tags are not fixed width by default, neither are any other HTML tags by default. Using a `width: 100%` and `max-width: Xpx` on your `<img>` tags would cover most of your bases for those too, letting them flex to their parent width with a sensible limit.

After that the only things restricting the layout are things you add. So as you're adding content make sure you think about what you want to happen to this content as the page shrinks and expands.

If you have a more specific case where you're struggling to find a good compromise there are a ton of resources for bootstrap and Yii.

Comment: Thanks. This does help, but I'm trying to understand if YII must be used as a widget for blocks/sections/"whatever you want to call it", or if I must actually just create my own divs and position them responsively. Thanks to the above comment, I know scaffolding is the first step, but I don't see any YII functions for this.

Comment: There's no real Yii-Bootstrap functions for the scaffolding as they're very simple classes and structures. Any Yii specific things would simply be syntactic sugar. Just remember by default your site is responsive, it's your content that messes things up. Fix it as you go, because there's no single, wrap it and forget solution.

Comment: Problem is, I'm trying the scaffolding examples, but none of them are working. The widgets work, but not the scaffolding stuff. Think some css isn't including then. ..

Comment: If your widgets are working then it's likely all CSS needed is included. It's all compiled from Less into a single file (if i remember correctly). Just try going back to a basic scaffold only page and work from there. without some more concrete examples it's difficult to say. If you do find a problem though your better off opening a new question now.

Comment: I had to add this --> 'components'=>array(
                'bootstrap'=>array(
                        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
                        'responsiveCss'=>true,
                ),

Comment: Ah of course, I completely forgot their was a separate responsive style sheet. Glad you got it going.